# what is the type 'repeat string'?

Tags: customize, lsp-mode, directory-local-variables

[Here](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pylsp/) it says that the type of `lsp-clients-pylsp-library-directories` is `(repeat string)`

How do I write my `dir_locals.el` file ?

I tried this but it doesn't work (see [here](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/issues/156))

```lisp
((lsp-mode . ((lsp-clients-pylsp-library-directories . '("contrib" "odoo")))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(repeat string)` is a [composite `customize` type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Composite-Types.html).

In *general* an easy way to find out is to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` to set a value, and then use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to check the value which was set.

In this specific case:

> `(repeat element-type)`
>
> The value must be a list and each element of the list must fit the type element-type. This appears in the customization buffer as a list of elements, with ‘[INS]’ and ‘[DEL]’ buttons for adding more elements or removing elements.

Hence `(repeat string)` is a list of strings.

---

> `((lsp-mode . ((lsp-clients-pylsp-library-directories . '("contrib" "odoo")))))`

Remember that a dir-locals file is implicitly data, not code; so your problem is that quote.

Try this:

`((lsp-mode . ((lsp-clients-pylsp-library-directories . ("contrib" "odoo")))))`